# nmake: can a batch file run as part of a make command block, affect the environment of the nmake.exe process?

Tags: nmake

I think in nmake if I do this:

```
 example :
        set value=77
        echo %%value%%
```

The result will display 77 on the console.

Is there a way for me to invoke a .cmd or .bat file that will affect the environment of the nmake.exe process?  Suppose I put the statement `set value=77` in a file called "setvalue.cmd".  Then change the makefile to this:

```
 example :
        setvalue
        echo %%value%%
```

I get:

```
%value%
```

Alternatively, if there's a way to set a macro within a command block, that would also work.  Or, a way to set the value of a macro from a batch file, even outside a command block.

Comment: You can not directly affect the environment, but you can get the return code and pass arguments to the batch file, so it is like calling a external program :-).

Comment: Okay the return value is interpreted only as errorcode inside the make and so you need to create a file or something to share values.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an nmake snippet during makefile pre-processing, and read that in. Assuming `batch.cmd` outputs valid nmake syntax, then

```
!if [batch.cmd >makefile.auto]
!error *** Could not create makefile.auto
!endif
!include makefile.auto
```

You should ensure `batch.cmd` sets `%errorlevel%` appropriately (e.g., `exit /b 22`).

`makefile.auto` can contain anything, but you would probably want stuff like `value=77`. A couple of points:

- Dereference `value` using nmake syntax (`$(value)`)
- You can pass parameters to `batch.cmd` if necessary (`[batch.cmd $(OBJECTS) >makefile.auto]`)