# Can't figure out how to read file from nmake

Tags: nmake

I am doing something like this:

```
all: 
    @SET /p filecontent= < somefile.txt
    @echo %filecontent%
```

However the `filecontent` variable does not seem to hold the contents of the file `somefile.txt`.

Comment: What do you hope to do with the content? There are probably better ways of doing this.

Comment: somefile.txt is a one-line file containing password which I do not want to hardcode in every makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply ensure `somefile.txt` is in acceptable nmake syntax, and then `!include` it. Thus:

```
c:>type somefile.txt
PASSWORD=secret
c:>type makefile
!INCLUDE somefile.txt
!MESSAGE Password is [$(PASSWORD)]
c:>nmake -nologo
Password is [secret]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to read a file that is not a valid nmake file using `!INCLUDE`. For examle if we have a version file `version` that contains a single line of text we can do that:

```
//version file
1.2.4

//makefile
VERSION= \
!INCLUDE <version>
```

It is not working if the file contains more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
# ---- vitaly.mak ----

target1:
# create and invoke a temporary cmd file
@<<mygetpassword.cmd
 @echo off
 setlocal
 @SET /p filecontent= < secret.txt
 @echo %filecontent%
 endlocal
<<

#--- END ---
```

I think [a cmd/bat file run within nmake.exe cannot affect the environment of nmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806463).  So you must *use* the password that you grabbed from the secret.txt within the temporary cmd file.

Comment: Just undone the misguided downvote here. :) The example in the question itself was confused (doesn't show what OP *really* wanted to achieve), and in the strict context of what is *actually* shown there, i.e. the command block of a rule, your answer is correct: *there* (or "at that time") you really can't change the NMAKE macros any more, AFAIK.